# Run encoder code simultaneously with other code in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, programming, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

```
volatile unsigned int temp, counter = 0; 
int county=0; 
void setup()
{
  
  Serial.begin(9600);   
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  attachInterrupt(0, ai0, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(1, ai1, RISING);  
}
 
void loop()
{
  county= (counter);
  if (counter>2000){
county=0;
  }
  temp = counter;
  
  Serial.println(county); // Encoder step counter
  
}

  void ai0() {if(digitalRead(3)==LOW) {counter++;}else{counter--;}}
  void ai1() {if(digitalRead(2)==LOW) {counter--;}else{counter++;}}
```

Dear all, **above arduino code is used for encoder as counter** and **code is quoted** from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QE4IQlwOgiA&t=42s&ab_channel=MakerTutor), the above simple code works fine. However, if I were to **add some code lines below the `Serial.println(county);`which actually delays execution time**, the counter will actually **skip steps and mess up the counter** which I am very dissapointed.

May I ask how to solve this issue, my thought is can arduino actually run 2 void loop simultaneously so that the c**ounter code can be run simultaneously and not be affected by other code lines which introduces delay time that mess up the counter**. Any help will be appreciated :)

```
volatile unsigned int temp, counter = 0; 
void setup()
{
  
  Serial.begin(9600);   pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP); pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP); attachInterrupt(0, ai0, RISING);attachInterrupt(1, ai1, RISING);  
}
 
void loop()
{
noInterrupts();
unsigned int county = counter;
interrupts();

  if (counter>2000){county=0;}
  
  Serial.println(county); // Encoder step counter
  
}

  void ai0() {if(digitalRead(3)==LOW) {counter++;}else{counter--;}}
  void ai1() {if(digitalRead(2)==LOW) {counter--;}else{counter++;}}
```

**PID code**

```
#include <PID_v1.h>
double Setpoint ;  double Input; double Output ;
volatile unsigned int temp, counterrr = 0; 
int county=0; 

double Kp=0, Ki=2, Kd=0;  
PID myPID(&Input, &Output, &Setpoint, Kp, Ki, Kd, DIRECT);


void setup()
{
  
  Serial.begin(9600);   
  Setpoint = 120;
  myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
  myPID.SetTunings(Kp, Ki, Kd);
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  attachInterrupt(0, ai0, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(1, ai1, RISING);  
}
 
void loop()
{
    
}

  void ai0() {
    if(digitalRead(3)==LOW) {
    counterrr++;}
    else{
      counterrr--;}

        county= (counterrr);
  Serial.println(county);
  Input = map(county, 0, 1024, 0, 1200);  // photo senor is set on analog pin 5
  myPID.Compute();
  analogWrite(9,Output); 
  Serial.print(Input);
  }
  void ai1() {
    if(digitalRead(2)==LOW) {
      counterrr--;}
      else{
        counterrr++;
        }

          county= (counterrr);
  Serial.println(county);
  Input = map(county, 0, 1024, 0, 1200);  // photo senor is set on analog pin 5
  myPID.Compute();
  analogWrite(9,Output); 
  Serial.print(Input);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

> can arduino actually run 2 void loop simultaneously

No, it cannot. All AVR based Arduinos (like Uno, Nano, Mega) have only one core, thus they can only execute one thing at a time.

The typical way to go is to just not introduce delays and divide up complex things into smaller parts. That way you can rapidly switch between different parts of the code, without blocking for a longer time. For humans it will then seem as if the parts are executed simultaneously, though they are actually executed successively.

To do timed things, you would use the non-blocking coding style from the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE. It uses the `millis()` function as a stop watch, on each loop iteration checking if enough time has passed since the last execution and executing again only if enough time passed. Much like you wouldn't bake a pizza and sitting in front of the oven until it is ready. You would regularly look at your clock to check, if enough time passed, doing other things in between.

---

That said, you changed the code after copying and mangled it in a weird way, so that it doesn't make much sense. Also the original code is not interrupt-safe.

The code in `loop()` has to do an atomic access to the volatile variable `counter`. This is to prevent the variable from changing in between reading it. Reading a single-byte variable (like one of type `byte`) is always atomic and cannot be interrupted, since this is one instruction, that will be finished before calling any interrupt service function (ISR). But `unsigned int` is 2 bytes big. So in rare cases the following might happen:

- First byte gets read from volatile variable into the non-volatile variable
- the ISR triggers and changes the volatile variable
- Second byte (which is now changed) gets read into the non-volatile variable

This can lead to occasionally corrupt data.

The typical way to do this is to temporarily disable interrupts, copy the volatile variable to a local variable and then enable interrupts again. Then you can use the local variable as a snapshot of the volatile variable without corrupting the data.

```
noInterrupts();
unsigned int local_counter = counter;
interrupts();
if(local_counter > 2000)
    ...
```

For your code you should also use the same mechanism as in the original code and only send the value over serial, if it really changed. Otherwise you will spam your serial connection, which automatically will slow down your code (since you are filling up the serial buffer faster, than it is send out, so that further calls to `Serial.println()` will block until enough space is available in the buffer).

Comment: Hi, I have used your code above, and it does not work, problem still the same. So, I have tried the millis() function in my updated code in my post :) but it still gives the same problem. May I ask if my updated code in my post is correct :) ?

Comment: Sorry, but that is a completely different code. In the first you used interrupts for the counting (which is good), in the second one you scrapped all the interrupt code. And because of that you didn't use any of my code (that is code only needed when using interrupts to count).

Comment: "it does not work, problem still the same" - I think first you really need to understand what the code from that video does. It seems, that you don't know that. And then you can start to change it. Currently you did show, what code you added to the original and also didn't state what exactly doesn't work. You need to provide a detailed description of what you expected to happen and what actually happened, together with the code and serial output of the code in question. Otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: Hi chrisl, I have updated my code to use noInterrupts() in my post, may I know if it is correct? :)

Comment: A big thank you for your answer, by the way, very concise :)

Comment: Better, but you are still  using `counter` in the if statement and for assigning to `temp`. The point is to use `counter` just for assigning its value to a non-volatile variable, in this case `county`. In the code after that (inside loop()) you should only use `county`.

Comment: And if you want to reset the counter, do this inside the ISR, so in `ai0()` and `ai1()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141086/discussion-between-maximus-su-and-chrisl).